# Filtering, storing into database and output textarea's text? Zend Framework 2.3.5

Tags: php, mysql, security, zend-framework2

I everyone,

I have a textarea. I need to storing its text into database Mysql and output it, but the output must be secure and preserve break line.

BEFORE STORING I use InputFilter validation:

```
       $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
       $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'Description',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                 array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
             ),
             'validators' => array(
                 array(
                     'name'    => 'StringLength',
                     'options' => array(
                         'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                         'min'      => 1,
                         'max'      => 30000,
                     ),
                 ),
             ),

         ));
```

AFTER STORING for the output of the text, I use:

```
echo nl2br(strip_tags($Description));
```

strip_tags for prevent XSS attacks and nl2br for preserve break lines.
So, it's secure? I've tried to save

```
"hi, how are yoy? <a href="www.hackered.com"> hackered </a>"
```

and into database the text is:

```
"hi, how are yoy? hackered"
```

I tried to store the first phrase directly into db and the output is as above. It seems safe.

This method is secure? There are some methods much secure?
I have this doubt because into Zend Filter reference it says:

> Warning
>
> Zend\Filter\StripTags is potentially unsecure
>
> Be warned that Zend\Filter\StripTags should only be used to strip all
>   available tags.
>
> Using Zend\Filter\StripTags to make your site secure by stripping some
>   unwanted tags will lead to unsecure and dangerous code.
>
> Zend\Filter\StripTags must not be used to prevent XSS attacks. This
>   filter is no replacement for using Tidy or HtmlPurifier.
>
> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#striptags

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right when you say :

> There are some methods much secure? I have this doubt because into Zend Filter reference it says:
>
> *Zend\Filter\StripTags must not be used to prevent XSS attacks*

Sure that [Zend\InputFilter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html) is one of the important components which let you improve your application security.
However, it is considred as a *wrong strategy* for preventing and blocking XSS attacks.

> **Zend\InputFilter:** this component takes care of scanning input to escape or remove illegal strings (HTML elements or filesystem paths), as well as transforming it to meet formatting requirements (stripping whitespace and newlines or changing string case).

The component provided by Zend Framework and dedicated for blunting XSS attacks is the [Zend\Escaper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.escaper.introduction.html). It provides five methods for escaping output depending on where the output will appear in the rendered page. Methods exist for escaping/encoding content within HTML page content, HTML element attributes, scripting elements, style elements, and URIs.

> **Zend\Escaper :**  this component offers a way to *escape output and defend from XSS and related vulnerabilities* by introducing contextual escaping based on peer-reviewed rules.

These are the escaping methods provided by Zend\Escaper:

- **escapeHtml**: escape a string for the HTML Body context.
- **escapeHtmlAttr**: escape a string for the HTML Attribute context.
- **escapeJs**: escape a string for the Javascript context.
- **escapeCss**: escape a string for the CSS context.
- **escapeUrl**: escape a string for the URI or Parameter contexts.

You could also refer to the documentation [Zend Escaper Theory of Operation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.escaper.theory-of-operation.html) for each method usage.

Please see this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-zend-security/index.html) on web application security with ZF2, particularly this section : [Blunting XSS attacks with output escaping](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-zend-security/index.html#N1023E)